# How to re-import single SVN branch to git?

Tags: git, git-svn

So... I goofed. I lost the git-svn repository I was using to mirror commits from SVN to git during a transition. I *should* have backed up my stuff, but I didn't.

Now there are a few commits on an old SVN branch that did not make their way over to the git repository.

Is there anything I can do now to transfer the commits on that SVN branch to the correct branch in the git repository? The branch already exists in the git repo, it's just out of date. It would not be an issue if I had to recreate or rewrite the history on that branch, so long as the main branch doesn't need to be changed and the branching-off-point is maintained in the history.

Comment: If `git svn` is already _tracking_ that svn branch, you can pull it off by running a `git svn fetch` indicating the last revision that you have in git for that branch.... up to HEAD or up to the latests revision on the svn branch.

Comment: Oh... but you mean that you lost the repo you were using to do the bridge `git svn` part? Do you intend to switch completely to git? Because if that's not what you intend to do and will continue using git and svn, you will need to mirror git svn again (at least the parts that you work with these days).

Comment: We will be moving to git completely, but because of how our build system works on older versions, that branch needs to stay on SVN. So it has gotten a couple of bug fixes that I want to move over to the git repo. I had a git svn clone tracking both where I could pull from SVN and push to the git repo, but that repo went away. I basically just want to mirror the one branch, so if I could just tell git-svn "that branch goes on this git commit" and then run `git svn fetch` and `git push -f that_one_branch`, that'd be the ticket.

Comment: Well, git svn can be adjusted to track only the branches you care for, and when fetching, you can tell it to _not_ look back before a certain revision so if all you care about is a single branch, it should be a simple task. What I would recommend is that you sit down a little bit running `git init` finding the way to _only_ provide the branch you care about (with `-T`, I guess) and then playing with `git svn fetch` from a certain revision using `-r some-limit-revision:HEAD`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn